# Event for Window Handle Click

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive

I'm trying to jump through some hoops at the moment in dealing with WPF's `SizeChanged` event on a Window. I have some custom code that I need executed **after** a user completes resizing the window, unfortunately there is no event that I have been able to come across for this so I have created a solution using Reactive Extensions to throttle the SizeChange events:

```
IObservable<SizeChangedEventArgs> ObservableSizeChanges = Observable
    .FromEventPattern<SizeChangedEventArgs>(this, "SizeChanged")
    .Select(x => x.EventArgs)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));

IDisposable SizeChangedSubscription = ObservableSizeChanges
    .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
    .Subscribe(x => {
        Size_Changed(x);
    });
```

Basically what this does is ensures that 200 milliseconds of no SizeChanged events must pass before it will call my custom code. This works fine however I have run into a problem that if the user drags the window handle out and continues to hold the mouse button down the code will still be executed. I want to be able to make sure that the custom code **cannot** be executed while the mouse button is down. I tried plugging into `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` but it is not fired when the window handle is clicked, only when the mouse is clicked inside the window's frame. Is there any similar event I can plug into for a mouse down that applies to the window handle? Or can anyone think of a suitable workaround for the problem that I'm having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows sends a dedicated message to notify the window that the modal size/move loop has exited.  WM_EXITSIZEMOVE, fired when the user lets go of the mouse button or presses Escape.  But yes, WPF doesn't expose it.  Google "wpf wm_exitsizemove" to find the interop code you want.  A good looking hit is [this blog post](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/01/09/a-wpf-behavior-for-window-resize-events-in-net-35)

Comment: Ah, forgot about that...this is probably a cleaner approach than my attempt above. :)

Comment: I probably should have mentioned I actually had some working code using interop services but was hoping to find something that was a little less heavy handed... Its hard to explain in code review why I need to pull in low level windows stuff for something that seems like it SHOULD be so trivial. Thanks though, the blog post is a good read.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably overkill, but to specifically address your "How can I figure out if the mouse button is down?" question, take a look at this P/Invoke wrapper:

```
public class ButtonObserver : IDisposable
{
    public struct MouseButtons
    {
        public bool LeftButton;
        public bool RightButton;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
    private const int VK_LBUTTON = 0x01;
    private const int VK_RBUTTON = 0x02;

    private Task _pollTask = null;
    private Subject<MouseButtons> _pollBuffer = new Subject<MouseButtons>();
    private CancellationTokenSource _canceller;

    public IObservable<MouseButtons> PollMouse(int pollDelayMs)
    {
        if(_pollTask == null)
        {
            _canceller = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _pollTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while(!_canceller.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    var mbLeft = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) != 0;
                    var mbRight = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) != 0;
                    _pollBuffer.OnNext(new MouseButtons{ LeftButton = mbLeft, RightButton = mbRight});
                    Thread.Sleep(pollDelayMs);
                }
            });            
        }
        return _pollBuffer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _canceller.Cancel();
        _pollTask.Wait();
        _pollTask = null;
    }
}
```

You can use it as:

```
void Main()
{
    var buttonObs = new ButtonObserver();
    var buttons = buttonObs.PollMouse(100).Where(mb => mb.LeftButton);
    using(buttons.Subscribe(mb => Console.WriteLine("Left button down")))
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    buttonObs.Dispose();
}
```